# How can there be a user directory in the URI?

Tags: php, get, uri

Apologies if this is a repeat, I really did not know what to search for this.

How can there be a user directory in the URI without creating a file for each user (which surely would be inefficient)? Or is that what is actually happening?

For example, youtube has "youtube.com/user/[username]" and it would take you to that specific profile. It seems similar to the GET request method (eg "?Profile=[username]"). Is this accomplished via PHP/.htaccess? If so then please tell me how to do via PHP/.htacess for my own use. If not, then I would still like to know the theory of how it is done.

Many thanks!
Jon

Comment: You should look for `url rewriting` in combination with the type of web-server you are using. There is plenty of information available about that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), i.e.:

Create an `.htaccess` file on the root of your website with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

The above will redirect any request to http://yoursite.com/user/janedoe to `user.php`. To get the value on user.php, you can use:

```
<?php
if(!EMPTY($_GET['user'])){
  $username = $_GET['user'];
  //janedoe 
}
?>
```

now, you can use the value of `$username` to, for example, query a database to get specific user details.

Comment: Oh okay! What does the `$1` signify?

Comment: `$1`, in this case, has the value `janedoe`. Basically, it will have the value of what come after `/user/`

Comment: Not that it matters logistically, but does it have to be `$1`? can it be anything? eg `$somelongname`

Comment: it needs to be $1, $2, $3, etc.. depending on the number of arguments, for example, http://yoursite.com/user/janedoe/london, to get the value of username and city you need, `RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1&city=$2  [NC]`

Comment: No, the URL doesn't change, but Apache sends the URL values (username, city, etc) to the `user.php` file on the background, just echo the value of username to verify that.

Comment: **Coment before:**
I added the code to the root .htaccess but the URI does not change.
<http://www.thefunnyzone.co.uk/user.php?user=abc>
My .htaccess file had rewrite rules which got rid of .php extensions.
**Reply:**
So how can I change the actually URL?

Comment: Please read my comment above, "__the URL doesn't change__" just go to `http://yoursite.com/user/janedoe` to get the value `janedoe` into `user.php`.

Comment: You may want to read [url-rewriting-for-beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: You're very welcome @jaunt:) If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+, tks !

Comment: Will do when I get 15 rep ;)